# silverspoon vs. farady - rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Mymodel gives NameError: uninitialized constant Patron::Error ... Patron::Session

Tags: elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5, searchkick, faraday

The simple call of

```
rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Mymodel
```

evokes the following error:

```
Reindexing Mymodel...
/Users/lutz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.12.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/patron.rb:39: warning: constant Patron::TimeoutError is deprecated
/Users/lutz/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.12.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/patron.rb:39: warning: toplevel constant TimeoutError referenced by Patron::TimeoutError
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Patron::Error

NameError: uninitialized constant Patron::Session
```

Here is my 'bundle list' output:

```
Gems included by the bundle:
* actioncable (5.0.2)
* actionmailer (5.0.2)
* actionpack (5.0.2)
* actionview (5.0.2)
* active_model_serializers (0.10.5)
* activeadmin (1.0.0.pre5 d4473e9)
* activejob (5.0.2)
* activemodel (5.0.2)
* activerecord (5.0.2)
* activesupport (5.0.2)
* addressable (2.5.1)
* arbre (1.1.1)
* arel (7.1.4)
* autoprefixer-rails (6.7.7.2)
* aws-sdk (2.9.7)
* aws-sdk-core (2.9.7)
* aws-sdk-resources (2.9.7)
* aws-sigv4 (1.0.0)
* bcrypt (3.1.11)
* bindex (0.5.0)
* bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
* bourbon (4.3.4)
* builder (3.2.3)
* bundler (1.13.6)
* byebug (9.0.6)
* callsite (0.0.11)
* case_transform (0.2)
* climate_control (0.1.0)
* cocaine (0.5.8)
* coffee-rails (4.2.1)
* coffee-script (2.4.1)
* coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
* concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
* database_cleaner (1.5.3)
* devise (4.2.1)
* devise_invitable (1.7.2)
* diff-lcs (1.3)
* dotenv (2.2.0)
* elasticsearch (5.0.4)
* elasticsearch-api (5.0.4)
* elasticsearch-transport (5.0.4)
* erubis (2.7.0)
* exception_notification (4.2.1)
* excon (0.55.0)
* execjs (2.7.0)
* factory_girl (4.8.0)
* factory_girl_rails (4.8.0)
* faraday (0.12.0.1)
* ffaker (2.5.0)
* ffi (1.9.18)
* figaro (1.1.1)
* formtastic (3.1.5)
* formtastic_i18n (0.6.0)
* globalid (0.3.7)
* has_scope (0.7.0)
* hashie (3.5.5)
* heroku (3.99.1)
* heroku-api (0.4.2)
* i18n (0.8.1)
* inherited_resources (1.7.1 0839b07)
* jbuilder (2.6.3)
* jmespath (1.3.1)
* jquery-rails (4.3.1)
* jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1)
* json (1.8.6)
* jsonapi-renderer (0.1.2)
* kaminari (1.0.1)
* kaminari-actionview (1.0.1)
* kaminari-activerecord (1.0.1)
* kaminari-core (1.0.1)
* launchy (2.4.3)
* letter_opener (1.4.1)
* meta_request (0.4.0)
* method_source (0.8.2)
* mime-types (1.25.1)
* net-ssh (2.9.2)
* net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
* netrc (0.10.3)
* nio4r (2.0.0)
* nokogiri (1.7.1)
* orm_adapter (0.5.0)
* paperclip (5.1.0)
* pg (0.20.0)
* polyamorous (1.3.1)
* pr_geohash (1.0.0)
* public_suffix (2.0.5)
* puma (3.8.2)
* rack (2.0.1)
* rack-contrib (1.2.0)
* rack-test (0.6.3)
* rails (5.0.2)
* rails-dom-testing (2.0.2)
* rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
* railties (5.0.2)
* rake (12.0.0)
* ransack (1.8.2)
* rb-fsevent (0.9.8)
* rb-inotify (0.9.8)
* rdoc (4.3.0)
* responders (2.3.0)
* rest-client (1.6.8)
* rsolr (1.1.2)
* rspec-core (3.5.4)
* rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
* rspec-mocks (3.5.0)
* rspec-rails (3.5.2)
* rspec-support (3.5.0)
* rubyzip (1.1.7)
* sass (3.4.23)
* sass-rails (5.0.6)
* sdoc (0.4.2)
* searchkick (2.2.0)
* seed_dump (3.2.4)
* shoulda-matchers (3.1.1)
* spring (2.0.1)
* spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
* sprockets (3.7.1)
* sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
* sqlite3 (1.3.13)
* sunspot (2.2.7)
* sunspot_rails (2.2.7)
* sunspot_solr (2.2.7)
* thor (0.19.4)
* thread_safe (0.3.6)
* tilt (2.0.7)
* turbolinks (5.0.1)
* turbolinks-source (5.0.0)
* tzinfo (1.2.3)
* uglifier (3.2.0)
* warden (1.2.7)
* web-console (3.5.0)
* websocket-driver (0.6.5)
* websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
```

I'm on silverspoon (devise, bootstrap, activeadmin) and 
OS-X 10.5.5 (Yosemite).
In the gem 'activeadmin' is also a Model named 'Patron' it is the Class for 'User' and 'Admin'. Could this interfere with the 'faraday' gem? How can I get rid of the error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested, the Class "Patron" from the silverspoon interfered with the Class "Patron" from faraday.
Setup a small "test" project and tried

```
rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Mymodel
```

everything went fine.

Solution: 
I renamed the Class 'patron.rb' in the models dir to 'customer.rb' and set the references in 'admin.rb' and 'user.rb' in the same dir from 'Patron' to 'Customer'.